# Bash: Loop until command exit status equals 0

Tags: linux, bash, loops, netcat

I have a netcat installed on my local machine and a service running on port 25565. Using the command:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 25565 < /dev/null; echo $?
```

Netcat checks if the port is open and returns a 0 if it open, and a 1 if it closed.

I am trying to write a bash script to loop endlessly and execute the above command every second until the output from the command equals 0 (the port opens).

My current script just keeps endlessly looping "...", even after the port opens (the 1 becomes a 0).

```
until [ "nc 127.0.0.1 25565 < /dev/null; echo $?" = "0" ]; do
         echo "..."
         sleep 1
     done
echo "The command output changed!"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You aren't actually RUNning the nc command, it's just a string.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but have you tried using **back ticks** instead of double quotes around `nc 127.0.0.1 25565 < /dev/null; echo $?` ?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

**Keep it Simple**

[Bash and other `sh` shells provide an `until` ... `do` ... `done` loop](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10):

```
until nc -z 127.0.0.1 25565
do
    echo ...
    sleep 1
done
```

*Just let the shell deal with the exit status implicitly*

The shell can deal with the exit status (recorded in `$?`) in two ways, explicit, and implicit.

Explicit: `status=$?`, which allows for further processing.

Implicit:

For every statement, *in your mind*, add the word "succeeds" to the command, and then add
`if`, `until` or `while` constructs around them, until the phrase makes sense.

`until nc` *succeeds*`; do ...; done`

* [Bash manual: until ... do ... loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html#index-until)

---

The `-z` option will stop `nc` from reading stdin, so there's no need for the `< /dev/null` redirect.

Comment: Nice, you get to see the command output message while retrying.

Answer (score 22):

You could try something like

```
while true; do
    nc 127.0.0.1 25565 < /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        break
    fi
    sleep 1
done
echo "The command output changed!"
```

Answer (score 3):

I personally like @Lee Duhem solutions better, although I think I have a better way of executing it.

This will run until it exits success:

```bash
while true; do
nc 127.0.0.1 25565 < /dev/null && break
done
```

This will run until it exits failure:

```bash
while true; do
nc 127.0.0.1 25565 < /dev/null || break
done
```

And a one-line equivalent of the first:

```bash
while true; do nc 127.0.0.1 25565 < /dev/null && break; done
```